# error "/clang:-1: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)" in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I've installed some pods in my Xcode project and run the pods init and pods update commands to create workspace file. I'm using Xcode 10.1 (because my code is in Swift 3 and no latest Xcode doesn't support that). I've tried searching internet a lot but every time I run the project, I'm getting this error -

> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker
> command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I've installed following libraries in my pod file -

[image: Pod Libraries]
[image: Libraries Pod]

I've tried to to change Bitcode to 'No', and Reflection Metadata Level to 'None' but it doesn't work. And yes, of course, I'm using the .xcworkspace file and not the .xcodeproj file. I did the pod update command too in terminal but that doesn't help either!

## This is my podfile -

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '10.0'

# Pods for myproj
target 'myproj' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'Alamofire'
  pod 'AlamofireImage', '~> 3.1'
  pod 'AlamofireObjectMapper'
  pod 'Eureka'
  pod 'Firebase'
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig'
  pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift', '5.0.0'
  pod 'SideMenuController'
  pod 'SnapKit', '~> 3.2.0'
  pod 'Fabric'
  pod 'Crashlytics'
  pod 'MGSwipeTableCell'
  pod 'SSZipArchive'
  pod 'RealmSwift'
  pod 'Realm'
  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native', :subspecs => [
    'Core',
    'DevSupport',
    'RCTText',
    'CxxBridge',
    'RCTNetwork',
    'RCTImage',
    'RCTAnimation',
    'RCTLinkingIOS',
#    'RCTWebSocket', # needed for debugging
    # Add any other subspecs you want to use in your project
  ]
  pod 'react-native-image-picker', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-image-picker'
  # Explicitly include Yoga if you are using RN >= 0.42.0
  pod "yoga", :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga"
  pod 'react-native-image-picker', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-image-picker'

 end
```

Comment: You've left out all the important parts of the error. Please [edit] your question with more details about the error.

Comment: Thats all I'm getting. Check this - 

symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
/clang:-1: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: The problem seems to be in React.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone is having similar problem, let me tell you that I was able to solve the problem by adding the following frameworks to Pods>React>General>Linked Frameworks and Libraries -

```
DoubleConversion.framework
glog.framework
folly.framework
Foundation.framework
JavaScriptCore.framework
yoga.framework
```